# Locale: Language name to Country / Language code

Tags: java, android, locale

**EDIT:**

I have a language name in English, nothing else. How do I get the code for it. e.g.:

- English -> en
- German -> de
- Spanish -> es
- Chinese -> zh

Answer (score 3):

**LanguageCode** enum contained in [com.neovisionaries:nv-i18n:1.11](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.neovisionaries%7Cnv-i18n%7C1.11%7Cjar) (or later) has `findByName` methods to get language codes whose names match a given pattern.

```
List<LanguageCode> findByName(String regex);
List<LanguageCode> findByName(Pattern pattern);
```

To get [ISO 639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) codes (2-letter, lower-case alphabets) for English, German, Spanish and Chinese:

```
String[] names = { "English", "German", "Spanish", "Chinese" };

for (String name : names)
{
    String code = LanguageCode.findByName(name).get(0).name();
    System.out.format("%s -> %s\n", name, code);
}
```

The above code snippet will output:

```
English -> en
German -> de
Spanish -> es
Chinese -> zh
```

### GitHub

https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-i18n

### JavaDoc

http://takahikokawasaki.github.io/nv-i18n/

### Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
    <artifactId>nv-i18n</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I would love to give this answer an upvote, but looking at the source code I see that you don't use a well known library, like the Locale in java, as backend. You re-define all the things, which imho is bad: you should then run after all the updates in the ISO 639-1 (which isn't a stable standard) and so on. To confirm this, there aren't major updates since 5 years ago: it's a burden to mantain such library. Did I see it right?

Answer (score 0):

We have to set the Language name and country name for locale to get this

```
// Locale(String language, String country)

Locale locale = new Locale("German" , "DE");
```

// print ISO3 country name for corresponding locale

```
System.out.println("Name:" + locale.getISO3Country());
```

This returns ISO3Country name as DEU

Comment: I am looking for a way to bypass this.

Comment: This leaves out the language, which remains in its full form